# currency converter using webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-phone-8, soap, currency

I'm trying to create simple currency converter between EUR/GBP/USD in my windows phone 8 databound application, but I'm getting some error.

I've added service reference to online currency converter to my app.

**This is the code that i wrote**

```
double value;
Converter.CurrencyConvertorSoapClient client = new Converter.CurrencyConvertorSoapClient();
value = client.ConversionRate(Converter.Currency.EUR, Converter.Currency.USD);
double total = value * double.Parse(znesek1.Text);
```

**Error - Program underlines client.ConversionRate and says SoapClient doesn't contain definition for ConversionRate**

I've already tried different methods like **ConversionRateCompleted** or **ConversionRateAsync**.

If i use:

```
value = client.ConversionRateAsync(Converter.Currency.EUR, Converter.Currency.USD);
```

i get the **cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'double'**

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Use the Object Explorer, or just IntelliSense to learn about the methods of the `client` object. In particular, the `ConversionRateAsync` method has different parameters than you think it does. It does not return a `double`. You have to use the event (`ConversionRateCompleted`, maybe) and look at the event args, which will probably contain the double result.